# Show search bar in navigation bar and large title also without scrolling on iOS 13

Tags: ios13, uisearchcontroller, large-title, preferslargetitles

I’m attaching a `UISearchController` to the `navigationItem.searchController` on iOS 13. This works fine: I can use the nice iOS 13-style search bar.

However, I’d like see the large titles and searchBar by default.

I set `navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false` because I want to see the search permanently on my screen, but the search bar replace large titles by default.

Does anyone know how is this is possible?

[Check this out](http://www.giphy.com/gifs/cl858LiJ4bahci0AVA)

```
navigationItem.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```

This is how it looks actually
[image: This is how it looks actually]

This is how I need to implement(large title and search bar both visible)
[image: This is how I need to implement(large title and search bar both visible)]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

For me it worked after adding following lines in the `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationController!.navigationBar.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: if you set navigation.navigationBar.sizeToFit(), the searchcontroller gets hidden and only the title is shown.

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to achieve the same thing all day long for my app as well and I finally did it.

I wanted to add a searchBar on a UITableViewController and I did it this way.

```
let searchController: UISearchController = {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "New Search"
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
    
   return searchController
}()
```

You first create a new UISearchController using a closure, that way you are able to use it globally in your code and customize it easier in the future.

Afterwards in viewDidLoad, you set the `searchSontroller.searchResultsUpdater = self` and the `navigationItem.searchController = searchController`.

For me it works perfectly after a lot of trial and error since I'm doing everything programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, working fine in my side

```
    private var search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        search.searchBar.delegate = self
        search.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        search.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        search.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        search.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here"
        self.navigationItem.searchController = search
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
    }
```

For large navigation bar use this

For full application navigation bar support please add this extension inside your code.

```
import UIKit
extension UIViewController {


    open func showNavigationBar(_ large: Bool,
                                _ animated: Bool,
                                titleColor: UIColor,
                                barTintColor: UIColor,
                                fontSize: CGFloat) {

        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = barTintColor
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = barTintColor
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
        if large {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
                appearance.backgroundColor = barTintColor
                appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: titleColor]
                appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: titleColor,
                                                       NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(resource: R.font.robotoMedium, size: fontSize)!]

                navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
                navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = appearance
                navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
            } else {
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: titleColor,
                                                                                     NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(resource: R.font.robotoMedium, size: fontSize)!]
            }
        } else {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: titleColor,
                                                                            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(resource: R.font.robotoMedium, size: 20.0)!]
        }
    }
}
```

And Then call this method simply

```
self.showNavigationBar(true, true, titleColor: UIColor.blue, barTintColor: UIColor.red, fontSize: 32.0)
```

If then Also not work then use this

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        search.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

**one more solution is that add one UIView with height 0 in storyboard and set-top with safe area and bottom with UIScrollView/UICollectionView/UITableVIew or something else scrollable view and Remove Direct Constraint between TopSafeArea And ScrollableView Top. I know maybe this is not a solution but I did in a storyboard.**

Comment: Totally appreciate your efforts, but unfortunately this is not working. Keep in mind: I want to have *large title and search bar visible by default*! Currently search bar is in place of large title.

Comment: Try this Extension for Large navigation bar, Also this will fix status bar color in iOS 13

Comment: The same result. I already have that extension setup correctly, and everything is in place, just search bar is over large titles.

Comment: can you share a screenshot, if possible then try bold content description

Comment: Screenshots updated in post! I appreciate your help!

Comment: can you please try same i have said in bold font

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201946/discussion-between-kiran-sarvaiya-and-bonnke).

Answer (score 0):

This code should work

```
class NavigationController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        createCustomTabBar()
    }

    func createCustomTabBar() {
    
        let firstVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeVC())
        firstVC.title = "Home"
        firstVC.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "house.fill")

        viewControllers = [firstVC]
    }

class HomeVC: UIViewController {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationItem.title = "Home"
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    }
}
```

[image: NavigationBar+SearchBar]

Comment: From Review:  Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks