# SwiftUI .searchable in iOS 15 - .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to achieve a Search Bar with the new .searchable modifier, with .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always). But if I start the App, the default position of the Search Bar is already "scrolled".

[image: When I open the App]

But this is what I want to achieve at the startup of the App:

[image: What I want to achieve]

This is my code:

```
struct SearchView: View {
    @State var searchText = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Search Bar")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Search")
            .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hacky Solution but it worked:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var searchText = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.white)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 1)
                
                List {
                    Text("Search Bar")
                }
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchText, placement:.navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
            .navigationBarTitle("Search", displayMode: .large)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, the Navigation Bar Title doesn't change to inline when scrolling anymore.

Comment: @XÆA-12 you can check now I've updated the answer. Initially, I thought you want a large title all the time.

Comment: Nice, works perfectly. Although it is a bit hacky :) Do you know if this is on purpose from apple or just a bug?

Comment: It only happens when you add searchable(text: to it. So it purposefully there for a reason, but don't know what it is. :)

Answer (score 1):

I came across here as I had the same problem.

For me it worked (also iOS 15.7) when changing the order (or maybe the VStack around the list ‍♂️).

My code looks like the following:

```
// somewhere where the SearchView is used:
NavigationView {
    SearchView()
}

struct SearchView: View {
    @State var searchText = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Text("Search Bar")
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        .navigationBarTitle("Search")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with using dependencies, here's a solution using [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/swiftui-introspect)

```swift
struct SearchView: View {
    @State var searchText = ""
    let names: [String] = ["Joe", "Dylan", "Jim", "Andy"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(names, id: \.self) { name in
                    Text(name)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Search")
            .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
            .introspectNavigationController { navigationController in
                navigationController.navigationBar.sizeToFit()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I found the original UIKit answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58727139/show-search-bar-in-navigation-bar-and-large-title-also-without-scrolling-on-ios/61449368#61449368) and found that asking the navigationController to call `sizeToFit()` fixed the issue (in my testing). From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622630-sizetofit), sizeToFit tells the navigation bar to resize itself to its own needs which is to have a large title.

I believe this was a SwiftUI bug in iOS 15 which is now fixed in iOS 16+ since this behavior no longer happens when using `.navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always)` with searchable.